# Xiaomi Mi 5C - Horrible Speed

Tags: xiaomi

I have a new Xiaomi Mi 5C ordered from AliExpress. When connected to the data network in Denmark, the internet is horribly sluggish. It seems to only be able to connect via Edge. Anybody knows a solution?

Note 1: that the same sim card in another phone provides 3G connectivity.

Note 2: all the settings are such that it should be using 3G when possible (e.g. Preferred Network Type = 3G)

Android Version: 7.1.2.

Comment: Only in Denmark, or generally? Because it could be the provider restricted (roaming) connections to that.

Answer (score 1):

Oki, what solved it for me were the following steps for enabling 4G on Xiaomi Mi5C:

1. dial *#*#1#*#*
2. in the menu select 'TEL_Assistant'
3. select 'Telephony' and then 'Radio Access Tec'
4. choose the '5 MODE' and then 'Save'
5. reboot/restart the device

Answer (score 0):

did you try changing the network model...is it stuck on edge..after changing the network model go to your network details and make shure your are on the selected network mode